# Use lodash to group array into tree "children" structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, lodash

Using lodash, I need to convert the following array:

```
[{
    text: 'apple',
    type: 'fruit'
}, {
    text: 'pear',
    type: 'fruit',
}, {
    text: 'potato',
    type: 'vegetable'
}, {
    text: 'water',
    type: 'beverage'
}]
```

Into the following format:

```
[{
    text: 'fruit',
    children: [{
        text: 'apple',
        type: 'fruit'
    }, {
        text: 'pear',
        type: 'fruit'
    }]
}, {
    text: 'vegetable',
    children: [{
        text: 'potato',
        type: 'vegetable'
    }]
}, {
    text: 'beverage',
    children: [{
        text: 'water',
        type: 'beverage'
    }]
}]
```

I've attempted to chain lodash methods like `groupBy` and `transform`, but am having a hard time getting to the resulting format I require.

Here's a skeleton of what direction I was heading:

```
_(arr).groupBy('type').transform(function(result, obj, type) {
    return result.push({
        name: type,
        children: obj
    });
}).value();
```

The issue I'm running into is `groupBy` turns my array into an Object, so I can no longer simply `push` onto an Array. Being relatively knew with lodash (around 4 or 5 months of experience), I wanted to see if others have already tackled such a requirement.

Comment: I will note, that using the following snippet works but I'm open to cleaner solutions: `_(arr).pluck('type').uniq().transform(function(result, type) { return result.push({ text: type, children: _.where(arr, { type: type }) }); }).value();`.

Comment: My only concern with this snippet is I lose reference to the original object, so if there were extra pieces of information like an `id` or `state` object, I'd lose that data in the `transform`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`_.reduce()`](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) instead of transform, because it lets you state the end product format:

```js
var arr = [{
  text: 'apple',
  type: 'fruit'
}, {
  text: 'pear',
  type: 'fruit',
}, {
  text: 'potato',
  type: 'vegetable'
}, {
  text: 'water',
  type: 'beverage'
}];

var results = _(arr)
  .groupBy('type')
  .reduce(function(array, children, key) {
    array.push({
      text: key,
      children: children
    });

    return array;
  }, []);

console.log(results);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I believe you posted exactly what I was trying to do and it works just as well as my snippet above, but I think your's is a lot better to use.